# Is it correct to say "conscientious of the fact"

Tags: phrasing

I'm writing out an e-mail blast and part of the sentence is

> I’d like to send this e-mail out as a reminder to everyone to be
>   conscientious of the fact that if there are changes to be made to...

Is that accurate to say *conscientious of the fact*?

Comment: What is your concern? Why wouldn't it be correct?

Comment: Are you worried about the definition of the word "conscientious", that it may be inaccurate in this context?

Comment: Yup! Does the definition match what I'm trying to say?

Comment: Check a dictionary http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conscientious then compare to _conscious_ http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conscious. _conscious of the fact_ is much more common - but it depends on what you want to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *ok* but I wouldn't do it. I think many people would think it's a mistake.

[Conscious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conscious) already means aware:

> 1. aware of... 2. *fully* aware of... 3. having the mental faculties fully active... 4. known to oneself; felt (e.g. conscious guilt)... 7. deliberate; intentional... 8. **acutely aware of or concerned about**...

where synonyms *aware* and *cognizant* refer to a realization or recognition of something about oneself or one's surroundings. So it is quite appropriate to say *concsious of the fact":

> Sitting among such friends, Russell could not help but be deeply conscious of the fact that he had changed a great deal since the days when... - NYT
>   It must be conscious of the fact that blacks are the potential victims of harmful discrimination... - NYT

*cognizant* (more formal) implies knowledge based on reasoning or information.

[Conscientious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conscientious) is more about principles, effort, morals, etc.:

> characterized by extreme care and great effort; "conscientious application to the work at hand"; "painstaking research"; "scrupulous attention to details"

where synonyms would be *painstaking*, *scrupulous*, etc.

Conscientious might be applied to being careful not to leak information (*conscientious record keeping*), strongly held moral convictions (*conscientious objector), etc.

Searching "conscientious of the fact that" does get you some hits, but not from "very respectable" sources (e.g. NYT, the Guardian, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on context, you are probably looking for the word "conscious". The term "conscientious" has its root in "conscience" and relates (generally speaking) to morality; a "conscientious person" is someone who has a desire to do the "right" thing, whatever that may mean.

"Conscious", on the other hand, can relate to awareness and presence of mind. To be "conscious of" something is to be aware of it, to keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In this day and age, the regular English-speaking guy on the street uses "aware." In published books listed at Google Books:

["I was aware of the fact that"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22conscious%20of%20the%20fact%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22I%20was%20aware%20of%20the%20fact%20that%22)

About 186,000 results

["I was conscious of the fact that"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22conscious%20of%20the%20fact%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22I%20was%20conscious%20of%20the%20fact%20that%22)

About 39,900 results

"Conscious" is of course correct, but more educated, intellectual, formal sometimes.